# Where should I ask questions about falcons?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'd like to ask a question about peregrine falcons and what happens if they swallow the birdring of another bird they've caught.

Which community would be the right one for this question? It doesn't seem to fit in *Biology*.

Comment: 1. What does "birdring" mean? 2. Why wouldn't it fit on [biology.se]?

Comment: @Blue oh, sorry I thought it would be called like that. I mean the thing that some birds have on their legs [Bird ringing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_ringing)

Comment: What's the question exactly? Like, if the falcon is yours (if you're doing falconry or something), it _might_ be on-topic for [pets.se] per [this meta post about semi-domesticated wild animals](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13). [Outdoors.se] also has a [birds tag](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds), so I guess that depends on what you want to ask...

Comment: @Blue their [what to ask](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page sounds like it was more about science and laboratory questions than about animals in general.

Comment: @shiny-metal Ah, I see. Thanks. I guess you'll have to ensure whether you can ask this [Biology Meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/) (worth a try anyway). Or perhaps [pets.se] or [outdoors.se] as Jenayah suggests.

Comment: @Jenayah in particular I was wondering whether it would be lethal to the bird. I've just saw one on a live camera in their nest and the mother swallowed it during feeding so I thought, hopefully it won't hurt it :-o

Comment: @shiny-metal Pets has "leg band" questions. The bands are made of different metals including aluminum, which [affects egg production](https://www.google.com/search?ei=pFLPXOblO9jb-gTfoovoDA&q=Aluminum+defective+eggshells+birds).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I have limited experience with [Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/), I think it might be on-topic there.

Their [[birds] tag](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birds) states:

> Egg laying, two legged, warm blooded, vertebrates with feathers. Use this tag to ask questions about our feathered friends. Questions on topic include birdwatching bush craft, hunting and any outdoors related bird based activity.

More interestingly, there is an apparently well received question about birds and tags: [Where to report bird with leg ring id?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/where-to-report-bird-with-leg-ring-id). The answers there suggest resources to report the bird's ID; as you said you saw that happen on a live channel, you might know the nest's location, and it might be worth putting a notice to the scientists/rangers monitoring the birds (if anyone is).

I suggest asking something along the lines of:

> I saw a bird swallow the birdring of another bird it was eating on live camera [YouTube link or something]. I am wondering whether that could harm them.
>
> 1. Can it actually cause harm or is it designed not to? (Researchers might have taken into account that the smaller birds could get eaten, when designing the tag)
> 2. In that case, or if I ever was to see such a thing myself while [hiking/hunting/whatever], should I report it, and how do I know who to contact?

Note that as said above, I'm no regular of Outdoors; you might want to ask on [their meta](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/) or [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp) whether this advice is completely off-tracks.

---

Purely for the record, if the falcon had been yours (for falconry for instance), it might have qualified for [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/), per [this meta about semi-domesticated wild animals](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13/are-questions-about-semi-domesticated-wild-animals-on-topic):

> I believe this can be simply addressed by "a pet is any animal kept in or around a household that is dependant upon that household for food, shelter, and care."

Note that I'm no regular of Pets.SE either...

Comment: If anyone from Outdoors/Pets reads this, please don't hesitate to tell me if I4m completely wrong. First site-recommendation answer, wouldn't want to give bad advice. :)

Comment: From TGO, but not much into the bird-related stuff there, but I am quite sure it fits quite fine with us. Biology might also fit, theres usually some overlap there I guess

Comment: It looks like it's fine on [Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/22056/can-a-tag-on-the-preyss-leg-harm-a-peregrine-falcon-if-eaten). Thanks!